# Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

This is my controller function

```
public function plist(){
    $plists = DB::table('panchayaths')->get(); 
    return view('webapp.panchayath list', ['plists' => $plists]);;       
}
```

This is my view

```
@foreach ($plists as $plist) 
<td> {{$plist['id']}}</td>
<td> {{$plist['pname']}}</td>
<td> {{$plist['total_ward']}}</td>
@endforeach
```

Comment: Did you try object access (`$plist->id`) instead of array access (`$plist['id']`)?

Answer (score 0):

did you try $plist->id. The get response is an object not an associative array.. if you want to use it as array in you blade add ->toArray() after the get().

Comment: toArray() won't work with stdClass objects, these aren't Eloquent models so they don't have any methods.

Comment: The result from `->get()` is an array of objects.

Answer (score 0):

in controller:

```
public function plist()
{
    $plists = DB::table('panchayaths')->get()->toArray(); 
    return view('webapp.panchayath list', ['plists' => $plists]);
}
```

OR if use Eloquent ORM:

```
public function plist()
{
    $plists = Panchayaths::all(); 
    return view('webapp.panchayath list', ['plists' => $plists]);
}
```

in view:

```
@foreach ($plists as $plist) 
    <tr>
        <td> {{$plist['id']}}</td>
        <td> {{$plist['pname']}}</td>
        <td> {{$plist['total_ward']}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

OR:

```
@foreach ($plists as $plist) 
    <tr>
        <td>{!! $plist->id !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $plist->pname !!}</td>
        <td>{!! $plist->total_ward !!}}</td>
    <tr>
@endforeach
```